# Installing Oracle Instant Client on Windows subsytem for linux

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, subsystem

With the latest windows 10 update, we now have ubuntu 14.04 in windows directly. 
I tried to install ruby on rails, mysql etc. All work perfectly.
The only thing doesn't work for me is the installation of oracle instant client. I followed instruction of this: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client

When I try to run sqlplus, I get the following error:

```
sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument
```

Comment: oh. goody. yet more software that requires you to hose system security.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install prelink
sudo execstack -s /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/bin/sqlplus
```